# Make sure variable exist throughout the application

Tags: cakephp

In my controller, I would like to set some values and have them exist (or live) throughout the different views in my app.

I read somewhere that I need to use beforeFilter function, but I am not sure if that is correct and how I go about doing that.

So in my controller I want to have

```
public function page1() {
  $this->Model->setId('123');
}

public function page2() {
  $this->Model->getId(); // would able to get the Id that was set from page1 function
  $this->Model->setName('Bob');
}

public function page3() {
  $this->Model->getId(); 
  $this->Model->getName();
}
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: You should provide a little more context as to why you want to do this, and what solution you are trying to solve. While it's possible, it's not something that's very common in an MVC app, and if you're new to CakePHP and/or MVC, then there's a good chance you're doing something wrong on an application design level.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to log-in a user and identity (use that users properties) throughout your application?

Comment: Well in my app, which is more of a wizard, where each view is doing is query a table (through SOAP WSDL). where it outputs a table and provide a link so that user can click on it so that on the next view it will either query another table or insert date. For that reason, some variable need to stay alive through the whole app, until the users reaches the final page of the wizard that they are in.

Answer (score 1):

To have this kind of "persistence" throughout the views, I guess the most simple approach is sessions.

Note that with the code you provided (I know is not a working example), you want the variable to be persistent inside a model, but that same model wont be maintained between actions of the same controller (or other controller for that matter).

You have to set that variable in sessions and retrieve it when you want to use it, or in the database and create methods in the model to get the last inserted id, for example.

So your code would be like

```
public function page1() {
   $this->Session->write('id', '123');
}

public function page2() {
   $this->Session->read('id');
   $this->Session->write('name', 'Bob');
}

public function page3() {
   $this->Session->read('id');
   $this->Session->read('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single model method that returns all your data in an array like

```
return array('varName' => $value, 'varName2' => $value2);
```

You can then call this model method from the controllers before filter and simply do

```
$this->set(ClassRegistry::init('MyModel')->commonViewVars());
```

If you would describe for what you think you need to do that I could give you a better advice like using requestAction() for example, this might be another option depending on what you're trying to do.

Depending on what data you want to pass to every page you should really consider to cache it. If its a menu for example cache it "forever" and just update the cache when the menu changes.

Comment: Well in my app, which is more of a wizard, where what each view is doing is query a table (through SOAP WSDL). where it outputs a table and provide a link so that user can click on it, so on the next view it will either query another table or insert data. For that reason, some variable need to stay alive through the whole app, until the users reaches the final page of the wizard that they are in.